# Is this error because GMail is blocked?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I wrote a simple app to send an email via GMail SMTP servers. However, it returns an exception at runtime.
At my workplace gmail is blocked (cannot access gmail.com). Is this error because of that?

```
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebExceptio
    n: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketExceptio
    n: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly resp
    ond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected h
    ost has failed to respond 74.125.113.109:587
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, it looks like it is related to that. The request could be blocked by the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

They are most likely blocking outbound traffic on port 587.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably yes.  There is a small possibility that the gmail server was down when you tried to access it, but it's clear that since you're blocked, you won't be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's because your network administrator has blocked this IP or port in the company's firewall.

Comment: @Kevin - actually it's no, as the SMTP servers and the web servers use different IP addresses and TCP ports.

Comment: gotcha - missed the distinction somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the exception is coming up because the connection failed, but it might not necessarily be because it's blocked. I can't even connect to that host:

```
> telnet 74.125.113.109 587
Trying 74.125.113.109...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.113.109: Connection refused
```

Edit: on second look, I **can** connect to that host from another machine. There might be other connectivity issues afoot.

Comment: I get "could not open connection to the host on port 587"